# Forcefully TakeOverCheckOut

Tags: document-library

I am trying to get the files which are checked out and take its ownership as below

```
List<SPCheckedOutFile> suspectFiles = ((SPDocumentLibrary)list).CheckedOutFiles as List<SPCheckedOutFile>;
foreach (SPCheckedOutFile file in suspectFiles)
{
    file.TakeOverCheckOut();
}
```

Running the following code gives me error as:

```
Some of the files cannot be checked out by you. They have been deleted or checked in by other users.
```

How can I forcefully take the ownership of the files.

FYI: These files have never been published

Comment: Make sure you are using a Site Collection Admin Account to do this.

Comment: all files should meet this "The file must be checked out and have no checked-in draft or published version."

Comment: @AmalHashim I am using a SCA account

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE these files are the ones which users uploaded for the first time and forgot to check it in.